# Keyboard Shortcut for Chrome's Developer Tools on Mac?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut to open Developer Tools on on Google Chrome on a Mac?

Ctrl-Shift-J does it on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[The default should be](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts) <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> for the JavaScript console).

Comment: By gum, you're right!!!

Comment: Seriously is there some reason for Chrome to have a different set of shortcut keys for Mac?

Comment: @Pacerier Except for F12 [they have the same shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts), just Ctrl -> Command, Shift -> Option.

Comment: @Pacerier lack of physical F12 key on Macbook Pro is a good a reason for me

Answer (score 15):

I think most Keyboard Shortcuts are listed in menus, when applicable.

[image: Example image]

Also...you can often define your own custom keyboard shortcuts in OS X by going to *System Preferences > Keyboard & Mouse > Keyboard Shortcuts*, then Adding a new shortcut that matches the name of the menu item you want to access. See [full instructions at OSXDaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2017/08/08/create-custom-keyboard-shortcut-mac).

If needed, [this OSXDaily.com article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/making-sense-of-mac-keyboard-symbols) has a good rundown on which symbols match which modifier keys.  Also, I always remember the ALT/Option key because it's symbol shows an 'alternate' path:  ⌥

Comment: you are absolutely right, but i thought it was | instead of I, so I struggled since then

Answer (score 6):

Windows uses `F12` you can map that to Developer Tools, which is what I did.

 icon → System Preferences... → Keyboard → Shortcuts (tab button)

- Click the ＋ Button
- *Application* select: **Google Chrome** and/or **Chromium** and/or **Google Chrome Canary**
- *Menu Item*: **Developer Tools**
- *Keyboard Shortcut*: `F12`
- Then hit Add (of course)

Of course you can put in whatever you want there instead of `F12`.

Comment: there is no + button in shortcuts tab ( using *macOS sierra 10.12.5 Ratina*)

Comment: Looks like apple support page isn't updated and my mbp is down right now, I'll update when I get my machine back online.  Thanks @pro.mean

Answer (score 1):

For people who want to use the **shortcut to F12** (like in every other browser and/or os), you can use the answer of *paulj*, but in the **Shortcuts** tab, you first need to click in the left list at **App Shortcuts**.

Then you get the + button to add **Google Chrome**:

[image: app shortchuts]

**Hint**: If you use another language, the dev tools has also another name.
For example in german I have to use **Entwicklertools**. You can find the correct name if you look in **Chrome**:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I have checked 'Search in anonymous and content script' and tried to use shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + J insted of CTRL + SHIFT + F. and surprisingly it started working.

[mentioned here setting >> shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8d7T.jpg)